# Angular ng-click not running without {{...}} firing on second click with jQuery

Tags: jquery, angularjs

The code that I have here fired on the second click.

This gets fired on first click, but produces errors in the console:

```
 <img ng-click="{{flip()}}" class="img-b" src="{{x.face}}">
```

This code gets  fired on the second click with no errors:

```
  <img ng-click=flip() class="img-b" src="{{x.face}}">
```

javascript:

```
        $scope.flip = function() {
            $('.img-b').on('click', function() {
                $(this).addClass('img-f');
                $(this).removeClass('img-b');
            });
        };
```

Comment: Questions on SO should be self-sustaining (i.e. not fully reliant on external sites, like JSBin). Post the *relevant* pieces of code here - please don't just copy-paste the entire JSBin. Try to reduce your code to isolate only the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are setting a jQuery event listener on the first click that doesn't run until the second click. Replace your ng-click with this:

```
<img ng-click="flip($event)" class="img-b" src="{{x.face}}">
```

Then update your flip method to look like this and it will work:

```
$scope.flip = function(e) {

    $(e.target).addClass('img-f');
    $(e.target).removeClass('img-b');

};
```

Really though, the Angular way would be to use ng-class on your img tag like so:

```
<img ng-click="flip(x)" ng-class="{'img-f': x.flipped, 'img-b': !x.flipped }" src="{{x.face}}">
```

And then your flip() function would just toggle x.flipped like so:

```
$scope.flip = function(x) {

    x.flipped = !x.flipped;

};
```